# 3D object translation distorts object

Tags: python, 3d

I am creating a 3D engine using this tutorial: https://www.davrous.com/2013/06/13/tutorial-series-learning-how-to-write-a-3d-soft-engine-from-scratch-in-c-typescript-or-javascript/

Whenever I multiply by the translation matrix it always distorts the image like this:

### Before

[image: Before]

### After

[image: Before]

The program is too long so here is where I multiply by the translation matrix, I am using the euclid.py library for all my matrix calculations:

```
worldMatrix = Matrix4().rotate_euler(
                mesh.rotation.y, mesh.rotation.x, mesh.rotation.z).translate(
                    mesh.position.x, mesh.position.y, mesh.position.z)
transformMatrix = worldMatrix*viewMatrix*projectionMatrix
```

and here is the translation method (part of the euclid.py library):

```
def translate(self, x, y, z):
    self *= Matrix4.new_translate(x, y, z)
    return self

def new_translate(cls, x, y, z):
    self = cls()
    self.d = x
    self.h = y
    self.l = z
    return self
```

Does anyone know any possible causes for this?

Comment: Add a before translation (or no translation) image so we can see what it's doing. Just having an after image doesn't give much of a clue to what's happening.

Comment: it is just the suzanne blender monkey, it is stretched on the y-axis (right hand, I will upload the before image soon.

Comment: I haven't read the tutorial, but have a couple of observations: Rotations always are relative to the origin, so to make an object appear to rotate about a certain point, the object is first translated so that the point would become 0,0,0 (i.e. by -x, -y, -z), then rotated, then translated back by the same amount in the opposite directions (i.e. x, y, z). Secondly, is it possible the distortions you're seeing are simply artifacts of perspective where things further away appear to be smaller? Lastly, I'd try a simpler object, like a cube or something, so you can see better what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative, make sure you're multiplying the matrices in the correct order.